# My name cannot be spelled

Tags: riddle

> My name cannot be spelled
>   It can't be heard or seen
>   It doesn't make sense but can be understood
>   It is a common name, yet most have never heard it
>   It is the most beautiful name, but most hate it

**What is my name?**

Disclaimer: I don't know the answer to this riddle as of yet.

Comment: Then there is a slight risk that your question is too broad.

Comment: Are you The Artist formerly known as Prince?

Comment: is it 'yeyhadfertagen'? (pronounced with a Scottish accent)

Answer (score 15):

I think the best possible answer could be

> ```
> "                   "?
> ```

Or more commonly known as

> **Silence**<sub>**Silence**</sub><sub><sub>**Silence**</sub></sub><sub><sub><sub>**Silence**</sub></sub></sub><sub><sub><sub><sub>**Silence**</sub></sub></sub></sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub>**Silence**</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub>**Silence**</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub>**.......**</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub>
> (I know, I'm pathetic :P)

My name cannot be spelled

> While you can write many onomatopoeias down, you can't write silence down, as shown above

It can't be heard or seen

> You can't hear or see silence, it is simply the absence of noise

It doesn't make sense but can be understood

> It's the absence of noise

It is a common name, yet most have never heard it

> It is very difficult to hear silence, because there is usually some sort of noise. It is a common name (often said by teachers or librarians)

It is the most beautiful name, but most hate it

> Most hate it because it means they can't speak

What is my name?

> It might be silence

Comment: @KateGregory, Thanks my spelling is awful :P